When HDMI is plugged into computer, run script
Setup
Headless single board computer (this one) which has an HDMI input
(To clarify, this is a port which takes in HDMI like a monitor would. It will receive HDMI feed, not export it, like a computer normally would. Most computers don't have an HDMI-in port, so it's necessary to specify that this one does and that's what we're talking about.)
Android device with HDMI output
Goal
As soon as the HDMI output cable gets plugged into the headless computer, a script is triggered which records the video stream. When it's disconnected, another script is triggered (to process the recorded video).
I haven't been able to nail down how to access an HDMI input programmatically, or how to edit the default behavior when one starts to receive input.
I'm guessing that Linux will have a way to do this, but if there's a solution with Android, Orange Pi Droid, or OpenWRT, I'll take it.
Thanks!
(I've read some other posts, but none of them had conclusive answers. Here are some of them:
Run a script on monitor connection/disconnection event
Triggering a script when I plug in an HDMI in Raspberry Pi 4
Commands to run when Connecting HDMI
)

You're getting a video stream from the output?

@tink I understand the question so that the single board computer with HDMI _in_put is the one on which the video stream should be recorded.

@AdminBee yes, that's right. The single board computer should be receiving and recording the video from the android device.

So the input is already connected, but you only want to record once the output has a cable plugged in?

@tink Whichever is simpler. I'd guess that it would be easier if the output was already connected, and the trigger to the input was that the input was being plugged in, but I'll definitely accept an answer that works the way you said.

I wasn't suggesting anything ... but you make a big point about the HDMI IN and then further down the question go on to talking about As soon as the HDMI **output** cable gets plugged into ... which is what triggered my first comment.

@tink HDMI in doesn't mean it's already plugged in.... it means that it receives the input. I think the setup is fairly clear. If you have any ideas, I'm happy to hear them.
